# How can I know the data paths of certain point of bezier curve?

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I´m trying to do some nodes animation and I don´t know how find the data paths of the points that define a bezier curve.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to figure it out yourself in the *Python Console*, or use the API docs as described here: [Blender/Python API Reference Usage: examples of how to use the API reference docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/info_api_reference.html#simple-data-access)

If you [search for `bezier` in the docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/search.html?q=bezier&check_keywords=yes&area=default), you will find `bpy.types.BezierSplinePoint.co` among others. At the bottom of the page, you can find

> **References**
>
> - [Spline.bezier_points](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/bpy.types.Spline.html#bpy.types.Spline.bezier_points)

So `bezier_points` is an attribute of a [Spline](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/bpy.types.Spline.html#bpy.types.Spline.bezier_points) object, which is in turn an attribute of a **Curve** object:

> References
>
> - [Curve.splines](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/bpy.types.Curve.html#bpy.types.Curve.splines)

The access path is therefore `Curve.splines[#].bezier_points[#].co`.

A Curve is an ID type:

> **Curve(ID)**
>
>   base classes — bpy_struct, ID

which could be, for instance, `bpy.data.curves['BezierCurve']`. Or if you want the data block of the current object, you would use `bpy.context.object.data`:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object
assert ob.type == 'CURVE' # throw error if it's not a curve

curve = ob.data
spline = curve.splines.active # let's assume there's only one
assert spline.type == 'BEZIER' # throw error if it's not a bezier

print(len(spline.bezier_points)) # print number of points
print(spline.bezier_points[0].co) # print coordinate of first point
print(spline.bezier_points[0].handle_left) # ... and its left handle's coordinate
print(spline.bezier_points[0].handle_right) # ... as well as the right one
```